# To find a sequence on $L^1$-norm equal to 2, converging a.e. to a function of $L^1$norm equal to 1.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, pointwise-convergence

I'm having some difficulty with the following two part problem:

(a) Find a sequence of functions $f_n$ in $L^1[0,1]$ converging a.e. to a function $g$ so that $\|f_n\|_1=2, \forall n$ but $\|g\|_1=1$.

(b) Show that for a sequence $f_n$ as above,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1|f_n(x)-g(x)|dx=1$$

For part (a), I'm not even sure where to begin looking for such a sequence. I understand that I need a sequence of functions whose area under the curve is constant 2, but that of the limit is 1. How does one go about constructing a sequence such as this?

For part (b), I applied Egoroff's theorem but I'm unable to proceed: Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists a set $E\subset[0,1]$ such that $m([0,1]\setminus E])<\epsilon$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on  $E$.

$$\left|\int_0^1|f_n(x)-g(x)|dx-1\right|\leq \int_0^1||f_n(x)-g(x)|-1|dx=\int_E||f_n(x)-g(x)|-1|dx+\int_{[0,1]\setminus E}||f_n(x)-g(x)|-1|dx$$

How do I proceed from here? Thanks for your time.

Comment: For each positive integer $n$, let $f_n(x)$ be $1$ for $0\le x\le 1-(1/n)$, and for $1-(1/n)<x\le1$, define $f_n(x)$ so $\int_0^1f_n(x)=2$.

Comment: Any thoughts about the comment and the answer that have been posted, omololo?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sorry, I got caught up with the holiday season. I was able to construct a sequence using your hint which is very similar to the one posted in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you may choose that $$g(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}2\quad 0\leq x \leq \frac12\\0\quad \frac12 <x\leq 1\end{matrix}\right.$$
And for $n\geq2$
$$f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}2\quad 0\leq x \leq \frac12\\\quad0\quad \frac12<x \leq 1-\frac1n \\\quad n\quad 1-\frac1n <x\leq 1\end{matrix}\right.$$
It is easy to check that $(f_n)$ converges to g a.e. . However, $\Vert{f_n}\Vert = 2$ and $\Vert g \Vert=1$.
For problem(b), by applying Egroff's theorem, you can get such a subset E that $m(E)=1-\epsilon$,$m([0,1]\backslash E)=\epsilon$ and$(f_n)$ converges to $g$ uniformly on E.Then, you may write the integral as follows:$$\lim_n\int_0^1|f_n(x)-g(x)|=\lim_n(\int_E|f_n(x)-g(x)|+\int_{[0,1]\backslash E}|f_n(x)-g(x)|)$$
Claim:$$\lim_n\int_{[0,1]\backslash E}|f_n(x)-g(x)|=1$$
First observe that, $$\int_{[0,1]\backslash E}|g(x)| <\delta$$by the fact $m(E)=1-\epsilon$ and the absolute continuousness of L-intergral. And$$\int_{[0,1]\backslash E}|f_n(x)|\to 1$$ since $\int_{E}|f_n(x)-g(x)|\to 0 $ and $1\geq \int_{E}|g(x)| \geq 1-\delta$.
And the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you use Egoroff's theorem, you claim to get a subset $E$ with $m([0,1]\setminus E)$ exactly equal to $1-\epsilon$. I only know that we can get  $m([0,1]\setminus E)<1-\epsilon$. Could you please explain this part?

Comment: It is just because of my laziness. What I want to express here is that the measure of $[0,1]\backslash E$ is small enough and E is very close to [0,1]. Sorry for my poor English writing.

Comment: I see, so we do want to write $m([0,1]\setminus E)<1-\epsilon$. Your English is adequate. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Sorry, another question. At the end, I agree and understand that $\int_{E}|f_n(x)-g(x)|\to 0 $ and $1\geq \int_{E}|g(x)| \geq 1-\delta$ but I don't see why this implies that $\int_{[0,1]\backslash E}|f_n(x)|\to 1$. Could you please explain this?

Comment: $\int_{[0,1]\backslash E}|f_n(x)|=\int_{[0,1]}|f_n(x)|-\int_{E}|f_n(x)|$. Here $\lim\int_{E}|f_n(x)|\to1$

Comment: And $\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|=2\  \forall n$